# How to position text in the center of this div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

here is the example:

[image]

Without the icons, the text is in the middle, when I add these icons (float: right), the text is moved to the left and is no longer in the middle? Any suggestion on How to place it in the middle?

Source code:

```
<div class="alert alert-success text-center text-uppercase" ng-show="vm.data">
    {{vm.showFoundItems(filteredItems.length)}}
    <a href="/RealSuiteApps/RealSuite/-1/WorkOrder/Index/" target="_blank"><img src="~/Content/images/icon-search35.png" class="pull-right" style="margin: -7px 0 -7px 10px" /></a>
    <img src="~/Content/images/icon-sort35.png" class="pull-right" style="margin: -7px 0 -7px 10px" ng-click="filterVisible = !filterVisible" />
</div>
```

**Update**

Well, thanks about DIV suggestion, it made this work, just needed to set appropriatly icons' margins to position them on the same line vertically

```
<div class="alert alert-success text-center text-uppercase" ng-show="vm.data">
    <div>{{vm.showFoundItems(filteredItems.length)}}</div>
    <a href="/RealSuiteApps/RealSuite/-1/WorkOrder/Index/" target="_blank"><img src="~/Content/images/icon-search35.png" class="pull-right" style="margin-top: -27px" /></a>
    <img src="~/Content/images/icon-sort35.png" class="pull-right" style="margin-top: -27px; margin-right: 10px" ng-click="filterVisible = !filterVisible" />
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks much better. Fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your images are effecting the useable width of there containing div. The easiest way for you to get your desired effect is to wrap your {{vm.showFoundItems(filteredItems.length)}} into its own containing div. Here is a link to a codepen example showing it done. [codpen](http://codepen.io/CodeBroJohn/pen/dpYXvv)

```
<div> {{vm.showFoundItems(filteredItems.length)}} </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked obviously, I just had to set margins for the icons to position them properly vertically

Comment: Yeah I had to do the same in my example because of the height of the images I used. I am sure you are using your images for some business reason, but just so you know bootstrap comes with Glyphicons you can use instead, should result in a faster webapp, plus they are a lot easer to add hover effects and click effects to. Glad I could help.

Comment: Yea, I know... I put glyphicons first but damn clients want these images :)